# ItextSharp optimize pdf file

Tags: c#, winforms, itext, wia

Hi I have code line like this

```
var lstimage = device.ScanTIFF(SelectedScanType.Value);

// Combine list Image to PDF
imageExtension = ".pdf";
var path = Path.Combine(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text + imageExtension);

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}

Document doc = new Document();
//doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);

var ms = File.Create(path);
{
    var pdf = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
    doc.Open();

    foreach (ImageFile item in lstimage)
    {
        var imagepdf = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance((byte[])item.FileData.get_BinaryData());
        //imagepdf.ScaleAbsolute(500f, 750f);
        //PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        //table.AddCell(imagepdf);
        doc.Add(imagepdf);
    }

    if (doc.IsOpen()) doc.Close();
}
```

My result pdf file is too large.

Just 3 image files (300dpi) gives me 35MB for the pdf file.

Do you have any idea how to help me optimize or reduce file to a smaller size?

---

Here is my file info

[MyFileInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHNMm.png)

Any C# library for reduce this Image without change DPI(Because i use this file to OCR)

Comment: You'll have to reduce the image size before adding them to itext, itext doesn't change the image size.

Comment: do you have any example to reduce ImageFile in this case and image quality not change too much after reduce ?

Comment: Here's one: https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
        iTextSharp.text.Image cabecera = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("images/logoCabeceraRecibos.png"));
        cabecera.ScalePercent(24f);
        cabecera.SetAbsolutePosition(0, documento.PageSize.Height - 70);
        //cabecera.ScalePercent(24f);
        documento.Add(cabecera);
```

Comment: This only reduces the visual image size in the page, it doesn't make the document smaller.